# How to efficiently close and open files in a Python logger class

Tags: python, logging, file-io

I'm implementing a simple logging class that writes out some messages to a log file. I have a doubt on how to manage the opening/closing of the file in a sensible and *pythonic* way.

I understood that the idiomatic way to do the writing in files is via the `with` statement. Therefore this is a simplified version of the code I have:

```
class Logger():
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='w', name='root'):
        self.filename = filename
        self.name = name
        
        # remove the previous content of the file if mode for logger is 'w'
        if mode == 'w':
            with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write('')        
            
    def info(self, msg):
        with open(self.filename, 'a') as f:
            f.write(f'INFO:{self.name}:{msg}\n')
            

logger = Logger('log.txt')

logger.info('Starting program')
```

The problem is that this implementation will open and close the file as many times as the logger is called, which will be hundred of times. I'm concerned with this being an overheat of the program (the runtime of this program is important). It perhaps would be more sensible to open the file at the moment of creation of the logger, and close it when the program finishes. But this goes against the "use `width`" rule, and certainly there is a serious risk that I (or the user of the class) will forget to manually close the file at the end. Other problem of this approach is that if I want to create different loggers that dump to the same file, I'll have to add careful checks to know whether the file is already open or not by previous loggers...

So all in all, what's the most pythonic and sensible way to handle the opening/closing of files in this context?

Comment: The most pythonic way would be to use the existing ``logging`` module ([clicky](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)) instead of re-inventing the square wheel.

Comment: Why are you trying to reimplement already existing functionality? I'm sure that it will be hard to do it better than python core developers.

Comment: I'm aware of the `logging` module. I want to implement a simpler logging myself because: 1) I want to learn 2) I'm using Spyder as IDE, and somehow `logging` conflicts with it and it just doesn't work for me (see for instance https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2572)

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the other comments that the most pythonic way is to use the standard lib, I'll try to answer your question as it was asked.

I think the with construct is a great construct but it doesn't mean it works in every situation.  Opening and saving a file handle for continual use is not unpythonic if it makes sense in your situation (IMO).  Opening, do something, and closing it in the same function with try/except/finally blocks would be unpythonic.  I think it may be preferred to only open it when you first try to use it (instead of at creation time).  But that can depend on the rest of the application.

If you start creating different loggers that write to the same file, if in the same process, I would think the goal would be to have a single open file handle that all the loggers write to instead of each logger having their own handle they write to.  But multi-instance and multi-process logging synchronization is where the stdlib shines, so...you know...your mileage may vary.